# Uploading and Extracting Topics from PDF in Flask

Tags: python, flask, pdf, apache-tika

I want to create a route in Flask in which a user can upload a PDF, and then I extract all the topics with their descriptions and store them in a list of dictionaries like [{title: 'abc', desc: 'xyz'}, {}, …]. I've tried a lot with different packages, but I couldn't make it possible. If anyone knows how, please help me
I am able to extract all of the text, but I want the text with their actual headings or titles

Comment: Have Apache Tika extract the PDF as XHTML, split then group on the `<h1>` / `<h2>` heading tags, and finally down-sample to plain text before returning?

Comment: @Gagravarr I used Apache Tika to extract the PDF as XHTML, but all of my titles and descriptions are wrapped in <p> tags.